# True difference between entity type and relationship type?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know that a relationship type is connected to one or more entity sets.
What I don't get is what the real difference between an entity type and a relationship type is?
To me they appear to function exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

entity types are like nouns.  And object that we want to store data about.
Customer and Invoice

relationship types are how those nouns relate to each other... like verbs.
received and sent

customer received invoice
invoice was sent to customer

Each entity within the entity type will have the same set of attributes, but in general different attribute values.  Each entity customer will have different addresses that an invoice was sent to.  Each invoice will have different invoice numbers and most likely totals.

I hope that helps, further reading and source of this example with diagrams can be found at http://www.databasedesign.co.uk/bookdatabasesafirstcourse/chap3/chap3.htm

Comment: I see but I've read that relationship types can have attributes as well. So I still don't really see the difference? How can you by looking at the code see if it's an entity type or relationship type?

Comment: In the example I have given where an attribute for a entity type is say an address then you will have attributes for relationship types as well.  Again, think of the noun and verb of this.  An attribute for this relationship type example would be how the invoice is sent or received, right?  Email, snail mail, hand delivered.  You have to example what you are talking about and determine.  You haven't given an example so all I am left with is to give a generic.  You can edit your question with real entity types and relationship types.